# Obtain the "brand new" effect of a fresh installation without fresh installation on Mac

Tags: terminal, mac, time-machine, install

When my computer starts slow down and the common operations don't have any effect I usually make a new installation and I have a "new" Mac.

The problem is that I have to configure again every single setting and considering that I started using terminal to customize my Mac, it would be a very long work to insert all terminal commands again, so finally, my question: what's the best way to really refresh a Mac without new installation?

Please don't answer like "Use Time Machine", because it will backup all the trash I'm trying to get rid of. Sorry if my question is duplicate but I cannot find an answer online and thanks for answering.

Comment: What exactly slows down - macOS does not usually slow down with age

Comment: To help more fully, we need to know: what model of Mac; installed macOS version; size of RAM; free space on boot HD; specific apps that appear to 'slow down', etc.

Comment: I have an iMac mid 2011, 4gb ram, El Capitan installed and 500gb hd with 241 gb free. By the way i have this idea: when you refresh your mac, you are deleting some trash files that are really hidden into your mac because as we know apple wants to preserve user to make a mess deleting files. My purpose was to access this files in order to delete them without a new installation; So to be more specific my question could also be: What kind of files contribute to slow down macintosh and how to access ALL them, maybe with terminal or some geek app? Hope this is more clear so thank you for answering